# session variable is showing undefined index

Tags: php

I have created 2 php test page for check session variable, at first page php session is working but second page it is show undefined variable please check below

first page code is below:

```
<?php
 session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "sanjeev";
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

second page code is below

```
 <?php
 session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

it is showing below error, undefined index name

What setting i Need to check in php setting to check this issue

Thanks

Comment: I've deleted my answer, as I realized I didn't understand your question. Are you trying to run this on a web browser?

Comment: Any chance you call the `session_start();` on your second page after you've already declared an `<html>` tag?

Comment: This is a repost of the original question which required changes [Session variable is not working in other page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71377782/1144627). Reposting as a separate question appears as closure avoidance.

Comment: Create a script with [`<?php phpinfo();`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to ensure the [session settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) are set appropriately for your server environment. If not passing the session id in the querystring, ensure `session.use_cookies` is enabled and the save path has write access by the user account assigned to the PHP process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session variable is not working in other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377782/session-variable-is-not-working-in-other-page)

Comment: @tola Yes please check ti.php url https://www.vinsfertility.com/vf/t1.php
t2.php url https://www.vinsfertility.com/vf/t2.php
t2.php you can see all php info

Comment: This is hostinger server and they do not know how to solve this server issue they are saying it is coding issue